# Convert Word to PDF - Disable "save" Dialog

Tags: c#, pdf, ms-word

I have a Word to PDF Converter written in c# which works fine except of one thing. Sometimes (on some Word Files) there is a Message in Background with **Save Changes in Source File -> YES NO CANCEL** - but I dont do any changes in Source file. I just wanna create a PDF File from the Word File, without changing anything.

So is there a Possibility to disable this Prompt, or set automatically to "NO". ?

Here is my Code:

```
// Create an instance of Word.exe
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word._Application oWord = new  Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();

        // Make this instance of word invisible
        oWord.Visible = false;

        oWord.DisplayAlerts = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdAlertLevel.wdAlertsNone;

        oWord.Options.SavePropertiesPrompt = false;
        oWord.Options.SaveNormalPrompt = false;

        // Interop requires objects.
        object oMissing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
        object isVisible = true;
        object readOnly = true;
        object oInput = input;
        object oOutput = output;
        object oFormat = format;

        // Load a document into our instance of word.exe
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word._Document oDoc = oWord.Documents.Open(ref oInput, ref oMissing, ref readOnly, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref isVisible, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing);

        // Make this document the active document.
        oDoc.Activate();

        // Save this document in Word 2003 format.
        oDoc.SaveAs(ref oOutput, ref oFormat, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing);

        // Always close Word.exe.
        oWord.Quit(ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing);
```

Comment: This doesn't convert a word document to PDF - it just opens a word document and **Saves a Copy** as Word 2003 (*.doc*) format.

Comment: Depends on the value of 'format'. If this is wdFormatPDF (17) it should create a PDF file (Office 2007 onwards).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you try passing false as the first argument to Quit?