# Office document to pdf

Tags: c#, .net, pdf, c#-4.0, printing

I simply want to **convert an office document to a pdf** file using c#.
Office is not installed on my server.

My plan is to use the "**Microsoft Print to PDF**" printer, but I could not find any working solution for this.
I just want to call the "Microsoft Print to PDF" **without showing a dialog** window.

How is this possible?

Comment: have you seen this SO thread? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12874185/convert-word-to-pdf-disable-save-dialog ? and this ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/607669/how-do-i-convert-word-files-to-pdf-programmatically

Comment: Yes, but this makes use of **Microsoft.Office** and Office is not installed on my server as I said in my post

Comment: This might be better on softwarerecs.stackexchange.com but the I think the answer is no.

Comment: Take a look at **docx4j.NET** here: http://www.docx4java.org/blog/2014/09/docx-to-pdf-in-c-net/  

This is the .NET version of docx4j. it is an open source (ASLv2) Java library for docx/pptx/xlsx, has features such as PDF output. Let us know if it serves your needs. Nuget package found here: https://www.nuget.org/packages/docx4j.NET/

Comment: @AramTchekrekjian This is really good. But I have a problem getting the right pdf file. There are comments like "#textbox#" in my pdf file. How can I turn this off? Is there more docu like the examples?

Comment: I am not quite sure if this is doable, but you can take a look at their official forums http://www.docx4java.org/forums/pdf-output-f27/ you might find more information or maybe you can ask anything you want in details.